# why is my internet speed slow on ubuntu 16.04. also have desktops with win 10 and ubuntu 18 ubuntu 16 is 100 mbs slower?

Tags: internet

I have fiber optic connection with 200mbs.desktop with windows 10 has 200 speed and desktop with ubuntu 18 runs at 200 desktop with 16 runs at80 why is this?

Comment: how did you measure this,online speedtest or via OS.

Comment: online speed test, speedof.me